# Write a function in R containing an if/else statement and rowSums(), defining how to handle NAs

Tags: r, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, na

I've been searching for answers and trying all I can think of, but nothing works:

I want to **write a function** to **add the values across rows** in a dataframe. It's easiest to write a function since I have so many columns and don't always have to add the same ones. Here an example of a dataframe:

```
ExampleData <- data.frame(Participant = 1:7,
                   Var1 = c(2, NA, 13, 15, 0, 2, NA),
                   Var2 = c(NA, NA, 1, 0, NA, 4, 2),
                   Var3 = c(6, NA, 1, 0, 1, 5, 3),
                   Var4 = c(12, NA, NA, 4, 10, 1, 4),
                   Var5 = c(10, NA, 3, 5, NA, 4, 4))
```

**The conditions:** If all values across a row are NA, the sum should be NA. If there is at least one value across a row that is a number (>= 0, or not NA), then rowSums should ignore NA's and add the values.

The best solution I've reached so far is:

```
addition <- function(x) {
  if(all(is.na(x))){
       NA
  }else{
       rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
addition(ExampleData[, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")])
```

The output is:  `[1]  8  0 15 15  1 11  5`

But it should be: `[1] 8 NA 15 15 1 11 5`

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: The `all(is.na(x))` is a problem.  It is doing for the whole dataset

Comment: Instead of `rowSums` use `sum` in the function and then you can `apply` the function row-wise. `apply(ExampleData[, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")], 1, addition)`

Comment: Insteaf of appply, you should use `rowSums` as the apply method is very slow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the `all(is.na(x))` is checking whether all the elements of the dataset are NA instead of by rows.   If we check the output of `is.na(data)`, it is a logical `matrix`.  A `matrix` is basically a `vector` with dimension attributes.  So, wrapping with `all` checks if all the elements are NA or not.

For example,

```
all(is.na(matrix(c(1:9, NA), 5, 2)))
#[1] FALSE
```

We can change the function to

```
 addition <- function(x) {
     rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE) *  NA^(rowSums(!is.na(x))==0)

 }
addition(ExampleData[, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")])
#[1]  8 NA 15 15  1 11  5
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly and helped me a lot. I had to think about the term after the multiplication sign for a while, but it makes sense now.